# How do I fix the following brew doctor errors?

Tags: homebrew

I'm new to homebrew and the terminal in general, but I'm enjoying learning.  I recently started receiving the following errors when I run brew doctor and haven't been able to find a solution:

```
   Error: Failed to import: php53-chdb
   No available formula for php53-chdb 
   Error: Failed to import: php53-graphdat
   No available formula for php53-graphdat 
   Error: Failed to import: php53-pdflib
   No available formula for php53-pdflib 
   Error: Failed to import: php53-raphf
   No available formula for php53-raphf 
   Error: Failed to import: php53-riak
   No available formula for php53-riak 
   Error: Failed to import: php53-xhp
   No available formula for php53-xhp 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-chdb
   No available formula for php54-chdb 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-graphdat
   No available formula for php54-graphdat 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-pdflib
   No available formula for php54-pdflib 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-raphf
   No available formula for php54-raphf 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-riak
   No available formula for php54-riak 
   Error: Failed to import: php54-xhp
   No available formula for php54-xhp 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-chdb
   No available formula for php55-chdb 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-graphdat
   No available formula for php55-graphdat 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-pdflib
   No available formula for php55-pdflib 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-raphf
   No available formula for php55-raphf 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-riak
   No available formula for php55-riak 
   Error: Failed to import: php55-xhp
   No available formula for php55-xhp
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please explain when, where, and how you're getting these errors. It's not likely that anyone will be able to guess what's wrong from just seeing a bunch of error messages.

Comment: After looking around in usr/local/library I found shorcuts to the items I received errors to in my Formula folder and deleted them which fixed the errors - hopefully this didn't mess anything up.  I was able to run brew update without a problem, so I think everything is in working - if anybody has any thoughts on what caused this in the first place, I'd be interested to know, THanks

Answer (score 13):

A simple fix from the homebrew PHP author's git page is:

```
brew tap --repair
```

More common issues: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php#common-upgrade-issues

Comment: Great help in my similar problem!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php; brew untap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

Comment: Or the opposite: `brew untap josegonzalez/homebrew-php; brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php`.

Comment: for all with the same issue - the repository is moved
`brew tap homebrew/php`